# From the formal definition of partial derivative, how do I justify taking independent variables constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For a function $f(x,y)$, the partial derivative of $f$ wrt. $x$ is
$$\tag{I} f_x= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}$$

1. From this how do I justify taking $y$ as constant?
2. Or how do I justify I can consider $f(x,y)=g(x)$ when doing (I)?

I could justify them by drawing a 3d graph, but I want to show it using equations.

I understand how to calculate a partial derivative. I'm looking for how to use (I), or some other definition/property to show that $y$ can be considered constant. Or I was hoping for a rigorous way to show $f(x,y)$ can be considered $g(x)$, to understand the 1st question, but I think it's making things more confusing...(equating a function of many variables to a function of few, directly).

Answer (score 2):

Both of your questions can be understood in terms of a slice of your multivariable function.

Define $g(x) = f(x,c)$ for some fixed $c$. Then we have $f_x = \frac{dg}{dx}$ (try proving this from the definitions), and the fact that we can treat $y$ as a constant falls right out. Here's an example; let $h(x,y) = xy^2$. Then as $h_x = dg/dx$, we can think of $\partial h/\partial x$ as $d/dx[xc^2]$ for any constant $c$, which amounts to differentiating $xy^2$ with respect to $x$ and treating $y$ as a constant.

Justifying the identification $g(x) = f(x,c)$ isn't really necessary. In this case, you're given a function, and you are *defining* a new function in terms of it. You might have to explain why $g$ depends only on $x$, but that's obvious from its definition.